# Web-scraping login

Tags: python, web-scraping, saml, wireshark, login-page

After being redirected to the login page of SAML using python, can I just POST my login data normally with the respective cookie? Or is SAML not that straight forward?

This is the redirected [page](https://login.monash.edu/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=fZJdb8IgFIb%2FSsN9C2KbWqImbl7MxGVGu13sZkFKLQkF1gNmP39Yt8zdeEHI%2BXjenPPCHHivHVsF35m9%2FAwSfPLVawNsLCxQGAyzHBQww3sJzAt2WD1vGc0Ic4P1VliNbpD7BAeQg1fWoGSzXqCPIxFCTGiV82mZzwjNeUHFrGqnoikLWpJiVpW0JbQQKHmTA0RygaJQxAGC3Bjw3PiYIpMyJXlKqnpCGSlZTt5Rso7bKMP9SHXeO2AYa3tSJuut4dBlsgmYNy1gDRglq9%2FpHq2B0MvhIIezEvJ1v%2F3je2sbLbNzPDcioHqn5cWA2NCEWHSdw2MM15umXMCYbWTLg%2FYpOJTsfix8UKZR5nTfveO1CdhTXe%2FS3cuhRsv5RZuNbgzL%2BzPy%2BMjjKHN8C12j%2F39g%2BQ0%3D&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fmoodle.vle.monash.edu%2Fauth%2Fsaml%2Fsso.php) I'm trying to login to using Python requests.

```
import requests

User = ***** 
Pass = *****

payload = {
    'UserName': User,
    'Password': Pass
}

session = requests.session()

moodle_url = "https://moodle.vle.monash.edu/login/index.php?authCAS=CAS"
response = session.get(moodle_url)
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()


SAML_url = response.url
response = session.post(SAML_url, payload)

print(response.url)
```

Doing this doesn't seem to be able to log me in as I still get back the same [url](https://login.monash.edu/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=fZJdb8IgFIb%2FSsN9C2KbWqImbl7MxGVGu13sZkFKLQkF1gNmP39Yt8zdeEHI%2BXjenPPCHHivHVsF35m9%2FAwSfPLVawNsLCxQGAyzHBQww3sJzAt2WD1vGc0Ic4P1VliNbpD7BAeQg1fWoGSzXqCPIxFCTGiV82mZzwjNeUHFrGqnoikLWpJiVpW0JbQQKHmTA0RygaJQxAGC3Bjw3PiYIpMyJXlKqnpCGSlZTt5Rso7bKMP9SHXeO2AYa3tSJuut4dBlsgmYNy1gDRglq9%2FpHq2B0MvhIIezEvJ1v%2F3je2sbLbNzPDcioHqn5cWA2NCEWHSdw2MM15umXMCYbWTLg%2FYpOJTsfix8UKZR5nTfveO1CdhTXe%2FS3cuhRsv5RZuNbgzL%2BzPy%2BMjjKHN8C12j%2F39g%2BQ0%3D&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fmoodle.vle.monash.edu%2Fauth%2Fsaml%2Fsso.php)

I've tried logging in manually using chrome and capture the package using Wireshark, following the HTTP Stream, the browser seems to GET the SimpleSAMLAuthToken cookie right after being redirected. I could not understand this as I don't see any POST containing my login ID and Password.

From my understanding, there should be some form of data POST-ing which I can mimic using Python request to get in, but filtering for "http" in Wireshark doesn't show any of that.

Is this the POST-ing problem or am I just missing a payload parameter or two?

I'm fairly new to both python and web scraping. Any debugging tip is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is a overkill... just take a look to the network tab in Google Chrome. There you can see that you POST data needs a format like this:

```
post_data = {'UserName': 'Monash\%s' User,
             'Password': Password,
             'AuthMethod':'FormsAuthentication'}
```

Also would be a great idea if you use a proper User Agent. If you don't do it probably you will be detected as a bot and web server will deny you access.

Another tip: Set proper headers in every POST requests (content-type, accept....)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!